# Prevent all of my contents of the page from resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to prevent all of the content on the page from moving, resizing while width page is under 1350 px. Min-width doesn't work for this and i don't know why.. so what can i do ?

Btw on my css code, for the `width, height, transformation: translate`, i'm using the value `vmax` , and not `px` or `%`. So the `min-width` maybe doesn't work with it, all of my elements keep resizing because they are using `vmax`, so they just adapt there size with the window size too.. :(

I tried this too, but still don't work :(

```
body {
    min-width: 1350px; 
}
```

[The code + preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/4BizatqN0GkGc7nedoBF?p=preview)

**(I'm trying to stop resizing the three white rectangle in priority when my browser width is under 1350px, but if we can tell to the page to stop resize all of the content when she is under 1350px, and only use a scrollbar to deplace the elements on the page, it will be cool !)**

See [this page](https://www.quora.com/When-using-CSS-how-can-I-prevent-my-DIVs-from-overlapping-when-I-shrink-my-browser) for exemple , when she is less than some px, the page stop from resizing and a scroll bar appear, i want the same result but i don't know how to do it ...

Answer (score 0):

you are using css dimensions that are relative to the viewport. [vmax vmin, vh, vw are relative](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/) to the viewport and thus react to resizing of the window. if you want fixed dimensions, you should use `em` or `rem`

edit: if you want to prevent the white boxes from resizing, you could add a `min-width: 450px` so they can grow but don't shrink beyond a point

Comment: But i need to use firstly the viewport dimensions, and when my browser width is under 1350px, i will change the dimensions of each elements in pixels ?

Comment: @ZahreddineLaidi see my updated answer. you can either specify min-width on the element or if you need more control utilise [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and override your whole css for these elements

Comment: I already tried this `@media(min-width: 1350px) {
    #tabcmp0 {

      width: 360px;

  }

  #tabcmp1 {

     width: 360px;

  }

  #tabcmp2 {

      width: 360px;

  }
}` , but this doesn't worked... :(

Comment: because its `max-width` if you want to override everything when its smaller

Answer (score 0):

`vmax` is not related to document size, but to actual browser size. Maybe absolute units like `px`, `rem`, `em` are a better solution in this case.

Comment: I really need to use the viewport dimensions at the beginning... but i can change the dimensions when my width will be less than 1350px, i already did it but it changes nothing.. :(

Answer (score -1):

For contional css, based on the specific width of the window, you can use media-queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1350px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

That way, you'll be able to define sepcific rules for each resolution / rule that you want.

Comment: I already tried this `@media(min-width: 1350px) { #tabcmp0 { min-width: 360px; } #tabcmp1 { min-width: 360px; } #tabcmp2 { min-width: 360px; } }` , but this doesn't worked... :(

Comment: Try using `height: auto;` or `width:auto;` for that purposes, that should do it.

Comment: My page still resize all of the elements, even after adding `height: auto;` or `width:auto;` on my body.

Comment: Sorry that it get too long, but you to separate and add it only for the triangle. Or otherwise please again again what do you to happen to the triangle while resizing? Good luck.

Comment: Can we directly say to the page to stop resizing all of the elements, like if she was frozzen, when she is less than 1350px ??